# Allowing socket access in apparmor

Tags: apparmor

I am using php-fpm running an application which needs to access e.g. `/var/run/redis/redis-server.sock`

In aa-complain or aa-enforce, logs are captured by the host (not the container) and appear in `/var/log/auditd/audit/log` e.g.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1572212584.295:206555): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 namespace="root//lxd-containername_<var-lib-lxd>" profile="/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.2" name="run/redis/redis-server.sock" pid=20078 comm="php-fpm7.2" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=100033 ouid=100113
```

A rule such as:

```
/var/run/redis/redis-server.sock rw
```

does not prevent this access being denied. How can I allow this access?

I'm unsure why the log message is misses the `/var/` off the front of the path.

EDIT: Looks like lxd/lxc isn't to blame, I've recreated this in a vm.

Answer (score 1):

I can at least answer why `name=` didn't have a leading slash and what side-effects that has. The kernel does not force opening of handles to include the leading slash, [which apparmor has issues with](https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/Release_Notes_2.5#path-name-lookup-and-mediation-of). The work-around is to add `attach_disconnected` to the flags of your process' apparmor profile. It would look something like...

```
profile usr.local.bin.taco_tuesday flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  [stuff]
  /run/redis/redis-server.sock rw
}
```

Using `/run` instead of `/var/run` because `/var/run` is very often a symlink to `/run`, and AppArmor only enforces on real-paths.

Comment: I fear I've done a https://xkcd.com/979/ and had since worked out the first part of your answer but the second is a useful tidbit I hadn't internalised. Thanks for your answer!